# Find $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}(\ln(x^2+1)-2\ln(x)) }{x^4}\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}\bigl(\ln(x^2+1)-2\ln(x)\bigr)}{x^4}\,dx $$
This question was asked on a Calculus Exam today, and I didn't manage to solve it. I tried Eliminating sqrt by putting $x^2+1$ as $t$, But it messes everything else.
Has anyone got hint how to solve this?

Comment: There was one missing closing parenthesis. I added it _after_ the second logarithm. Please confirm that the expression now in the formula is the correct one.

Comment: Yeah that's right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}(\ln(x^2+1)-2\ln(x)) dx}{x^4}$$
$$=\int \sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{x^2})}\ln(1+\frac{1}{x^2})\cdot \frac{1}{x^3}dx$$
$$=-\int \sqrt{(1+\frac{1}{x^2})}\ln(1+\frac{1}{x^2})d(1+\frac{1}{x^2})$$

Substitute $z^2=1+\frac{1}{x^2}$ and you get
$$-\int z\cdot 2\ln z\cdot 2zdz$$
$$=-4I=-4\int z^2 \ln z \,\ dz$$
$$=-4(z^2 \int \ln z-2\int z\cdot (\int \ln z dz)dz)$$
$$=-4(z^2 (z \ln z -z)-2\int z\cdot (z \ln z -z) dz)$$
$$=-4(z^3 \ln z -z^3-2\int (z^2 \ln z -z^2) dz)$$
$$=-4(z^3 \ln z -z^3-2I +\frac{2z^3}{3} )+c$$
$$=-4z^3 \ln z +4z^3+8I -\frac{8z^3}{3}+c$$

Therefore $$-4I=-4z^3 \ln z +4z^3+8I -\frac{8z^3}{3}+c$$
$$-12I=-4z^3 \ln z +4z^3-\frac{8z^3}{3}+c$$
$$-4I=\frac{1}{3}(-4z^3 \ln z +4z^3-\frac{8z^3}{3})+c$$
using $\int \ln z= (z \ln z -z)$

The answer is $$\frac{1}{3}(-4z^3 \ln z +4z^3-\frac{8z^3}{3})+c$$

You need to substitute $z$ back.

Comment: Your integration by parts looks strange to me.

Comment: @mickep Oops sorry I differentiated $\ln x$ instead of integrating !! Correcting it right now.

Comment: @mickep Is it okay now?

Comment: It would probably have been easier to switched role in your integration by parts: $\int z^2\ln z\,dz=(1/3)z^3\ln z-\int (1/3)z^3\cdot 1/z\,dz$...

Comment: @mickep Yup perhaps. Tried to do it in a different way just. Nothing else.

Comment: By above methods I'm getting a different answer, Does that mean this answer is incorrect?

Comment: No not all. Integration of a function can yield more than one function as answers. They are all correct as many functions can have the same derivative. Tell me if my working has any problem.

Answer (score 8):

The $\ln x$ term implies that we consider $x>0$ only.

Since you can write
$$
\log(1+x^2)-2\log x=\log(1+1/x^2)
$$
and
$$
\sqrt{1+x^2}=x\sqrt{1+1/x^2}
$$
your integral can be written
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{1+1/x^2}\ln(1+1/x^2)}{x^3}\,dx.
$$
The substitution
$$
u=1+1/x^2
$$
seems to fit *very* well. I leave it to you to do the details.

Comment: hmm..you win! +1

Comment: I hate being the second one posting a very similar answer, so I give you a ↑ for sympathy.

Comment: Ha, I take it however I get it!

Answer (score 5):

$$
\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}\left(\ln\left(x^2+1\right)-2\ln x\right)}{x^4}=\frac{x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x^4}
$$
let set $u=1+\frac{1}{x^2}\implies du = -\frac{2}{x^3}dx$
we can see that your integral becomes
$$
\int \sqrt{u}\ln u\frac{du}{-2}
$$
this can be solved by parts

To depart away from @Mickep answer lets try the sub $x=\tan t$ we find
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\sec^2 t}\ln \left(\sec^2 t\right)-\ln \left(\tan^2 t\right)}{\tan^4 t}\sec^2 t dt=\frac{\sec^3 t\left(-2\ln \sin t \right)}{\tan^4 t}dt = -2\frac{\ln \sin t}{\sec t \sin^4 t}dt = -\frac{2\cos t \ln \sin t}{\sin^4 t}dt
$$
setting $v =\sin t\implies dv = \cos t dt$ we find
$$
-2\int \frac{\ln v}{v^4} dv
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}\left(\ln(x^2+1)-2\ln x\right)}{x^4}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\left(\ln\left(x^2+1\right)-\ln x^2\right)}{x^4}\ dx$$
$$=\int \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\ln\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}\right)}{x^3}\ dx$$
$$=\int \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\frac{dx}{x^3}$$

let $1+\frac{1}{x^2}=t^2\implies \frac{dx}{x^3}=-t\ dt$
$$\int t\ln(t)(-t\ dt)$$$$=-\int t^2\ln(t)\ dt$$
using product rule, $$=\ln(t)\int t^2\ dt-\int \left(\frac{d}{dt}(\ln(t))\int t^2\ dt\right)\ dt  $$
$$=\frac{t^3}{3}\ln(t)-\frac{1}{3}\int t^2\ dt$$
$$=\frac{t^3}{3}\ln(t)-\frac{t^3}{9}+C$$
Now, substitute  $t=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}$ & simplify